# Backbone.listenTo vs this.listenTo

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Inside a `Backbone` object (model,view,router), we can call `this.listenTo`

like so

```
var BodyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(Backbone, 'prevent-scroll', this.preventScroll);
  },

  preventScroll: function(prevent) {
    // .prevent-scroll has the following CSS rule: overflow: hidden;
    this.$el.toggleClass('prevent-scroll', prevent);
  }
});

// And now from anywhere in the code:
Backbone.trigger('prevent-scroll', true); // prevent scrolling
```

however, is there a way to use

`Backbone.listenTo`, instead of `this.listenTo`? I don't see any examples of this online, but I don't see why it shouldn't exist.

Also, one more question in the call

```
Backbone.trigger('prevent-scroll', true);
```

where is the `true` argument being passed to? I don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at the annotated Backbone source. 
http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-19

There is a clear way to do this.
The naive standpoint is that you should be able to pass around messages on the front-end wherever Backbone is, not just wherever Backbone.Views, Backbone.Models, etc, are.

If you put this on your front-end, it will work:

```
    Backbone.Events.on('event1',function(msg){
        alert(msg);
     });

    Backbone.Events.trigger('event1','hiiii');
```

Not only that, you can also simply do:

```
    Backbone.on('event1',function(msg){
            alert(msg);
     });

    Backbone.trigger('event1','hiiii');
```

this is because of this call in the Backbone source:

```
_.extend(Backbone, Events);
```

`Backbone.Events` is:

> a module that can be mixed in to any object in order to provide it
>   with custom events. You may bind with on or remove with off callback
>   functions to an event; trigger-ing an event fires all callbacks in
>   succession.

for example:

```
    var object = {};
    _.extend(object, Backbone.Events);
    object.on('expand', function(){ alert('expanded'); });
    object.trigger('expand');
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't explain what you need it for, it makes no sense to use listenTo outside the context of a particular collect/view/model instance. The whole point of `listenTo` is so one object can listen to another (from inside itself) and **perform cleanup** on the destruction of that object, as well as bind the context to `this`.

e.g. in a View `this.listenTo(this.model, ..)` is better than `this.model.on(...)` because when the view is destroyed the listener will be removed.

If you are outside of that context you just use the `.on` method, which does the same thing.

```
var someModel = new Backbone.Model();
someModel.on('change:text', function(model, newValue) { ... }
```

If you wish to share a model you can either pass it down through views (if you have set up views to have a hierarchy). Or like with your other template question you are better off setting up your app to use RequireJS. Then you can have a global AppState model for instance that would look something like this:

```
define([
    'backbone'
], function(Backbone) {

    var AppState = Backbone.Model.extend({

        ...

    });

    // Return as a singleton (instantiated).
    return new AppState();
});
```

That way every other component could require it in and since it is a singleton they all have access to the same model and can listen to events on it.

Comment: thanks for the info, it will be useful. I don't see why there should be a limitation. Backbone serves as some sort of message bus, and if it can trigger events then I don't see why it can't listen to events also, even without Backbone objects/elements. I am sure there is a way to hack the source to do this, but like you say I probably won't have any reason to listen to events outside of the context of a Backbone object anyway so I might not bother.

Comment: @AlexMills the event prototype is extended into model/view/collection/router, and each instance you make of them has it's own `events` hash (object) - there is no global event bus to listen to which holds all the events so I'm not sure if it's possible

Comment: I was looking at the source, it looks like you can hack it, so that you can call Backbone.Events.listenTo .... see here http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-27

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript `this` is a special keyword, it holds the object that you're currently working with so to speak.

For example,

```
$("button").on("click",function(event){
console.log($(this));
})
```

This would log out to the console all the properties of the button you clicked.

I would also have a look into callbacks.

Comment: ummm sorry this didn't really answer the question