# this.listenTo in Backbone initialize method - null model or null collection

Tags: backbone.js

Say I have Backbone view like so:

```
        var Footer = Backbone.View.extend({

           model:null,
           collection:null,

           initialize: function () {

                        this.listenTo(this.model,'change',this.render);
                        this.listenTo(this.collection,'reset',this.render);

                }

           render: function(){

                }

         });
```

if this.model and this.collection are null at the time of the this.listenTo calls, I know that no error is thrown (that's good) but will the listeners get registered if the model/collection is null at the time of the listenTo call and only later are instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, if the object you are trying to listen to is null nothing is bound, you can see this by having a look at the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-27) for [listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo)

```
Events.listenTo =  function(obj, name, callback) {
    if (!obj) return this;
```

Notice how backbone just returns from the function.

Comment: thanks that reminds me, I wanted to look at the source to find if I could listen events that were not part of a Backbone view/model etc

Comment: You can listen to whatever event you want.

Comment: yeah, your answer helped me answer my own question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015284/backbone-listento-vs-this-listento